# How can I append the value of emberjs variable in object to my anchor tag href?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want something like below

```
<a href="/Admin/MenuEdit/{{ResAdmin.adminController.selectionMenu}}">Edit Selected Menu</a>
```

selectionMenu is a variable in `ResAdmin.adminController` Ember Object.

Answer (score 7):

In order to declare a binding for an attribute, you'll need to use `bindAttr`. You can use this helper to bind an attribute either to a global path or to a variable in the current context, such as your view.

For instance, you might have a template like this:

```
<a {{bindAttr href="menuUrl"}}>Edit Selected Menu</a>
```

Which is bound to a property in your view, like this:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    menuUrl: function() {
        return "/Admin/MenuEdit/" + this.get("App.adminController.selectionMenu");
    }.property("App.adminController.selectionMenu)            
});
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgeb/B7a7j/) for this example.
    ​